# can someone explain what this line of ruby code does?

Tags: ruby

Found in the [Ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide).

```
1 > 2 ? true : false; puts 'Hi'
```

I assume this always returns `Hi`, but how do I read it?

Comment: Note: I understand the terneary operator (? :).  The part that confuses me is ; puts "Hi"

Comment: It is a bad example. It does not mean much.

Comment: To expand on @sawa's comment, it was listed as an example after saying to use spaces after semicolons, and when to use spaces for other syntax. It's probably contrived because there's rarely a good reason to use semicolons - it's the only place in the style guide that mentions semicolons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If 1 > 2 then true, else it is false.

However, it will print `hi` whatever the condition result.

It is the same that:

```
if 1 > 2 then
  true
else
  false
end
puts 'hi'
```

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like I was overthinking this one.

Answer (score 2):

You may read this like

```
1 > 2 ? true : false # first line of code
puts "Hi"  #second line of code
```

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby compiler reads it like this:

```
1.>( 2 )
puts "Hi"
```

Ternary operator ? : is redundant. Comparison 'greater than' symbol :> is actually a method of Numeric class.

Answer (score 0):

If 1 is greater than 2 then true, else then false. 
Then puts Hi

http://buddylindsey.com/c-vs-ruby-if-then-else/

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon is an inline way of separating two lines of code.  So it's just like

```
1 > 2 ? true : false
puts "Hi"
```

which is equivalent to

```
false
puts "Hi"
```

And of course a line that just says `false` will do nothing (except for a few cases, like if it's the last line of a function definition in which case the method returns false if it reaches that line).

Answer (score 0):

1 > 2 ? true : false; puts "Hi"  that means

```
if 1 > 2 
  return true
else
  return false
end
puts "Hi"
```

Here each time means the result is whatever it will print "hi" because we print "Hi" in outside of condition.

but

```
if 1 > 2
 puts "1 is not greater than 2"
else
 puts "1 is greater than 2"
end
```

you can also test in your console

```
1.9.3p125 :002 > if 1 > 2
1.9.3p125 :003?>   puts "1 is not greater than 2"
1.9.3p125 :004?>   else
1.9.3p125 :005 >     puts "1 is greater than 2"
1.9.3p125 :006?>   end
1 is greater than 2
 => nil
```