# What does this ruby/rails code mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am going through this tutorial: http://blog.assimov.net/blog/2011/04/03/multi-file-upload-with-uploadify-and--carrierwave-on-rails-3/

One of the lines of code is:

```
@photo = params[:id] ? @property.photos.find(params[:id]) : @property.photos.build(params[:photo])
```

I don't understand what the `?` and `:` do in that line, or what it is supposed to accomplish.

Comment: possible duplicate of [can someone explain what this line of ruby code does?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701262/can-someone-explain-what-this-line-of-ruby-code-does)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this: [:? ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a)

Comment: Ok that's easy enough.  Thanks a bunch